# v-data-table customizations to cells

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a component called 'my-table' that has a v-data-table in it.  I have many other components that use it to display a basic table by passing in their own headers/data.

I would like to take it one step further and allow other components to dictate customizations to the cells.  As an example, maybe one component wants a particular column to use v-icons instead of text. Maybe a completely different component wants a cell to be editable when clicked on, etc.

What is the best way to go about this in vue? Do I literally have to copy/paste the myTable code into the other components and modify it there?  Is Vue able to inject a template/component that has specific rules for that table, and if so is there an example?  It seems like v-html cannot handle all necessary tags and ends up stripping them.  Is there a better way that I'm not thinking of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a condition (v-if) rendering on a named slot on your component, basically a slot sets to render a predefined set of code you have but it can vary o what you pass to the child component, or in this case you can limit to a boolean value to render, passed as a prop to the child component.

[See:Component Slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html)

[See: Named Slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Named-Slots)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what you're suggesting. Are you saying I should make a custom slot for every possible table customization and place them all in the myTable file?

Comment: Not exactly, you can have as many slots as you want in your component, but where you are referencing this component you can have the slots needed to render. 

For example:

You can have a table that has all the components, but whenever you are referencing this table you can use only the needed slots in order to have the view you want.
 

Refer to the named slots documentation that i provided, they provide a good example on this issue.